# How to get Angular Leaflet Directive to render correctly inside Angular Material Design?

Tags: leaflet, material-design, flexbox, angular-material, angular-leaflet-directive

The [Angular Leaflet Directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive) looks to the dimensions of the parent container to determine what its correct size is before it make requests from the server for map image tiles. [Angular Material Design](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) uses the [flexbox CSS](http://flexboxfroggy.com/) property to set dynamic widths and heights of containers.

The problem is Leaflet looks up to the parent and finds a width and height of 0 0. Here is an [issue queue question on the problem](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/issues/950) with almost the solution.

(I already have the answer. Just sharing.)

Answer (score 1):

I created a directive that adds the Angular Material `flex` attribute to the `leaflet` directive at compile. This makes the container width 100%. Then it gets a promise from Leaflet which is called when the map object is finished rendering. The method `map::invalidateSize()` is called which forces Leaflet to check the size which is set correctly at this point of the parent container.

```
(function() {
    angular.module('live')
        .directive('ttLeafletFlexFit', leafletFlexFit);

    leafletFlexFit.$inject = ['$timeout', 'leafletData'];

    function leafletFlexFit($timeout, leafletData) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            compile: compile
        };

        return directive;

        function compile(tElem, attrs) {
            tElem.attr('flex', '');

            // A hack to get Leaflet to fill the flex container.
            // @link https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/issues/950
            leafletData.getMap().then(function (map) {
                $timeout(function() {map.invalidateSize()});
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

Then add an attribute on the leaflet directive element.

```
<leaflet tt-leaflet-flex-fit></leaflet>
```

Comment: It took me a little while to figure out that flex and Angular Material was my problem but no time at all to implement your fix. Thanks!